# How to pass value from Activity to anywhere in same Activity?

Tags: android

I am working on a download project.I want to pass a string value in activity to anywhere in same Activity
My request: when I click the button,String str pass to DownloadFromURL class and get the string
Please help me

code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShow;
Intent i;


public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 
private static String file_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/progressdialog/hive.jpg";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String str = "file";//Value that I want to pass to DownloadFromURL class
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
        }
    });
}


class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();


            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            String res = "";//This should String that I want to get from FirstClass 
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+res+".jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }


            output.flush();


            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..  Use `String str = ""` as **Global variable** in **FirstActivity** as like `Button btnShow;`

```
btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            str = "file";//Value that I want to pass to DownloadFromURL class
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
        }
    });
```

Or

```
   new DownloadFileFromURL(str).execute(file_url);
```

and `AsyncTask` **class**

```
  class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

   String url;
    //  constructor
   public DownloadFileFromURL(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

         //as your code you can use url this the DownloadFileFromURL
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the `DownloadFileFromURL` was declared outside of the activity scope

Comment: @MarioStoilov but it is defined in the scope of the activity in this case so it will work

Comment: @MarioStoilov and now see my edit also my friend. that will work.

Comment: @tyczj yes it is, I was just pointing it out in case he decides to extract this class in a seperate file

Comment: I tried this yesterday and this not worked.But It works now.thank u

Answer (score 2):

```
new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url, str);
```

And in your `doInBackground` method:

```
URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
String str = f_url[1];
```

Comment: How to add my string in f_url[1]?

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . You pass al your strings to the `execute` method like execute(str1,str2,str3...) and you can access them as an arry in the `doInBackground` method

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SharedPreferences and you could also use the data in other acitivies.

```
public void saveStageInstance(string data){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("dataName", data);
        editor.commit();

    }
    public Boolean loadStageInstance() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("dataName", false);
    }
```

Comment: Although this would work, I do not recommend to use SharedPreferences with data that changes frequently (if he downloads files on a regular base), is big (the file might be a video) or accessed in different threads (Shared prefs can have weird results when used asynch).

Comment: He's saying he needs only a string and is requesting only when a button is pressed.